# Warning Variable 'jpegICI' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

The title to this Question is the VS 2010 warning. I would like to somehow initialize the variable or do whatever to clear out the warning. (kinda nice having no warnings even though website works). However this variable is of type ImageCodeInfo so I can't just assign it zero or "".

Here is what triggers the warning:

```
 outputBitmap.Save(SaveLocation, jpegICI, encoderParams)
```

Above this is the code below that checks to see if image being uploaded is jpeg

```
Dim arrayICI As ImageCodecInfo() = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
Dim jpegICI As ImageCodecInfo
Dim x As Integer
For x = 0 To arrayICI.Length - 1

    If (arrayICI(x).FormatDescription.Equals("JPEG")) Then
        jpegICI = arrayICI(x)
        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Always tag your question with the appropriate language tag. Visual Studio 2010 supports a number of languages.

Comment: Ah yes. I was wondering what other tags I could use. thanks

Comment: `Dim jpegICI As ImageCodecInfo = Nothing`  The compiler sees that it is set conditionally (inside the If) so it warns you.  If it is a function, just return instead of Exit For and get rid of the var

Comment: "= Nothing" worked. Thank you Plutonix. Please post as an answer so I can accept. Not bad for a Sunday late afternoon. Stack Overflow rocks.